# Apply NA to the rows that meet a condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like such:

```
 set.seed(126)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(c(1:100, NA), 10), b=sample(1:100, 10), c=sample(1:100, 10))

    a  b  c
1  65 48 19
2  46 15 80
3  NA 47 84
4  68 34 46
5  23 75 42
6  92 87 68
7  79 28 48
8  84 55  9
9  28 43 38
10 94 99 77
>
```

I'd like to write a function that transforms all values in all columns to NA if `df$a` is `NA` However, I don't want to just assign `b` and `c` the value of `NA`, rather I would like a function that turns all columns in the data.frame to NA if the condition `is.na(a)` is met, no matter the number of columns.

Comment: It does - I'm an idiot. The answer below works perfectly.

Comment: Hmm, don't be too harsh on yourself.

Comment: Thought I accepted @DavidArenburg - sorry about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are just looking for

```
df[is.na(df$a), ] <- NA
#     a  b  c
# 1  65 48 19
# 2  46 15 80
# 3  NA NA NA
# 4  68 34 46
# 5  23 75 42
# 6  92 87 68
# 7  79 28 48
# 8  84 55  9
# 9  28 43 38
# 10 94 99 77
```